# How to test changes in call volume over time?

Tags: time-series, spss

I have carried out a study on change of call volume over a year (oct 07-mar 09).  What statistical test on SPSS software can I use to show the difference in call volume on a day by day basis and on a monthly basis?

Comment: With only 1 or 2 data points for each month, you don't have a lot with which to test results on a monthly basis. As for the day-to-day results, you'll want to make your hypothesis more specific. You might test for an early-late difference (e.g., first few months vs. last few); for the presence of particular days that stand out from the rest (outliers in the distribution); or other effects. What is most important or interesting to you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My data refers to whether call volumes increased to an advice line for pharmacists after a change in legislation occured affecting their daily practice. I would like to find out whether there is a particular day of the week that would show a larger number of calls than the others. I would also like to see whether there was a particular month where the call volume seemed to be particularly high. My hypothesis is that the number of calls will be higher immediately after the change in legislation and this will then decrease over time.  I hope this information helps.

Comment: @Miranda do you have any data on call content? This would seem to be the most direct way to test the hypothesis about legislation affecting call volume - if you observed a certain category of calls related to the legislation increase.

Comment: No we did not need to look at the content, just the volume of calls.

Comment: Can you share the data? (just moved @IrishStat's edit to this comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you have daily data for 2+ years , you can construct a time series model that could include day-of-the-week;week=of-the-year;holiday/event structure. This model could then be used to detect level shifts or local time trends which could illuminate the nuances in your data via Intervention Detection schemes. I have been building these kinds of models for years with great success. One can identify particular days of the month that are consistently exceptional and even incorporate Monday-after Friday Holidays and/or Friday before Monday Holidays. Unfortunately SPSS does not support this kind of analyses so you might have to look elsewhere or write your own "stuff". In addition one can test for significant break-points or change-points in time where parameters have changed significantly using procedures like the Chow Test.